# linq to xml initializing array

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, initialization, anonymous-types

I have two classes - `Cd` and `Track` which I'm trying to read into from a XML file using Linq.

`public Cd(string t, string a, string cat, DateTime rls, Track[] tr)`
`public Track(string t, int l)`

The XML looks like this.

```
<media>
  <cd>
    <artist>Ozzy Osbourne</artist>
    <album Name="Bark at the moon" Type="Metal" Tracks="5" ReleaseDate="1983-12-10">
      <track Length="300">Bark at the moon</track>
      <track Length="235">You're No Different</track>
      <track Length="567">Now You See It (Now You Don't)</track>
      <track Length="356">Rock 'N' Roll Rebel</track>
      <track Length="120">Centre of Eternity</track>
    </album>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Journey</artist>
    <album Name="Escape" Type="Rock" Tracks="4" ReleaseDate="1981-07-31">
      <track Length="300">Don't Stop Believin'</track>
      <track Length="235">Stone in Love</track>
      <track Length="567">Who's Crying Now</track>
      <track Length="356">Keep on Runnin'</track>
    </album>
  </cd>
</media>
```

The code I'm trying to use is as follows

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("dbxml.xml");
    var temp = from cds in xdoc.Descendants("cd")
    select new Cd(
        cds.Element("artist").Value,
        cds.Element("album").Attribute("Name").Value,
        cds.Element("album").Attribute("Type").Value,
        DateTime.Parse(cds.Element("album").Attribute("ReleaseDate").Value),
        new Track[] { // One Track reads fine..
            new Track(cds.Element("album").Element("track").Value,
               int.Parse(cds.Element("album").Element("track").Attribute("Length").Value)) 
               }
        );
```

The problem is that I don't know how to initialize the array with all the tracks read from the XML file. I could wrap the whole query in a `.ToList()`, use an anonomyous type and `foreach`-it but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in just one run with linq.

`cds.Elements("album").Elements("song")` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` collection and somehow that should be added to the array as a range and turned into a string and an int, or something to that affect. Any help out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var temp = from cds in xdoc.Descendants("cd")
            select new Cd(
                cds.Element("artist").Value,
                cds.Element("album").Attribute("Name").Value,
                cds.Element("album").Attribute("Type").Value,
                DateTime.Parse(cds.Element("album").Attribute("ReleaseDate").Value),
                cds.Element("album").Descendants("track").Select(t => new Track(t.Value, int.Parse(t.Attribute("Length").Value))).ToArray() 
                );
```

Easier to read (imo) using properties:

```
select new Cd()
    {
        Artist = cds.Element("artist").Value,
        Album = cds.Element("album").Attribute("Name").Value,
        Type = cds.Element("album").Attribute("Type").Value,
        ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse(cds.Element("album").Attribute("ReleaseDate").Value),
        Tracks = cds.Element("album")
                    .Descendants("track")
                    .Select(t => new Track()
                    {
                      Name = t.Value,
                      Length = int.Parse(t.Attribute("Length").Value)
                    }).ToArray()
    };
```

You should consider adding a default constructor to `Cd` and `Track` and exposing public properties or use named parameters - this would make the LINQ statement much more readable.

Comment: This worked out of the box - thank you! I do actually have a default constructor and properties for all the fields. Would you care to elaborate on how this query would be more readable by using properties?

Comment: I find property assignments easier to parse as a reader, so this could be i.e. `select new Cd() { Artist = ... , Album = ... , }`, same for Tracks

Comment: Yes, that seems like a much more readable query. Thank you! I need to study my C# in a nutshell some more. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your LINQ, replace

```
new Track[] { // One Track reads fine..
    new Track(cds.Element("album").Element("track").Value,
       int.Parse(cds.Element("album").Element("track").Attribute("Length").Value)) 
       }
```

with something like this:

```
( from t in cds.Element("album").Elements("track") 
  select new Track(..., ...)
).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I got the first track of every album repeated for all the remaining tracks. Five Bark at the moon and four Don't stop believin'. Maybe I messed something up?

Comment: I typo'ed Element and IIRC it is Elements that you'd want. BrokenGlass' answer is using .Descendants which may be the better way.